# MySQL : Calculate percentage composition based on a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have the following MySQL table named Table1

[image: MySql table]

The Result can either be Pass or Fail. I want to calculate the percentage pass for each id.

Result must be the following table based on formulae: For each id, count Pass / Total Counts for given id. For example id 2 have 2 pass and 2 fail therefore percentage pass = 2/4

[image: Intended Result]

My Sql Query below is giving wrong results

```
SELECT  id,COUNT(Result) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(Result) FROM aa WHERE Result = 'Pass') as Percent
FROM aa
GROUP BY id
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation like that:

```
select id, avg(result = 'Pass') as pass_ratio
from mytable
group by id
```

In the context of `avg()`, condition `result = 'Pass'` is evaluated as `1` if true and `0` if false. You can just average these values to get the ratio of "pass".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group by` and conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT(case when result = 'Pass' then 1 end) * 100 / count(1) as Percent 
  FROM aa 
GROUP BY id
```